# Chromium based browser is not navigate to new url when run with selenium

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have create a simple WFA chromium based browser. When I connect it with the selenium, it do open the browser but it does not navigate to the new URL. The command window also show like below. How can I do to manipulate the chromium based browser like using the chrome driver?

```
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("Includes");
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.BinaryLocation = "M:\\browser\\bin\\x86\\Release\\browser.exe";
driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, opt, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(8));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
```

> Starting ChromeDriver 87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355}) on port 59708
> Only local connections are allowed.
> Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
> ChromeDriver was started successfully.
> [1119/220859.772:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(48)] compileToBinary(257):
> C:\fakepath(107,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
> C:\fakepath(102,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
>
> [1119/220859.812:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(48)] compileToBinary(257):
> C:\fakepath(124,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
> C:\fakepath(119,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
>
> [1119/220859.895:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(48)] compileToBinary(257):
> C:\fakepath(121,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll
> C:\fakepath(116,1-13): warning X3557: loop only executes for 1 iteration(s), forcing loop to unroll

**UPDATE**

After refer others online example, I modify the the code to following

```
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("Includes");
ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
opt.BinaryLocation = "M:\\browser\\bin\\x86\\Release\\browser.exe";
opt.AddArgument("start-maximized");
opt.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
opt.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
opt.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
opt.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
opt.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, opt, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(8));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.youtube.com/");
```

Then the command window show like following, but it still unable to navigate to new URL.

> Starting ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.87 (cd6713ebf92fa1cacc0f1a598df280093af0c5d7-refs/branch-heads/4183@{#1689}) on port 64644
> Only local connections are allowed.
> Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
> ChromeDriver was started successfully.

Note: **My WFA chromium based browser only have a web browser interface.**

Comment: The error literally tells you the problem - *Only local connections are allowed*. The docs tell you that you need to tell the driver which IP addresses are allowed to be used. ([see here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriverService_WhitelistedIPAddresses.htm))

Comment: Do you have any example to show how to do the local connections? I am quite new for it and don't know how to do

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem too.
selenium does not work well with winforms
The solution I found is
Geckofx from nuget
It works really well with winforms

Geckofx-Core.dll
Geckofx-Winforms.dll

Comment: Which version of chrome driver is supported by the Geckofx?

Comment: the Geckofx work with firefox and cefsharp works with chrome so try cefsharp i hope this will work for you